# How am I supposed to replace any null values with "-" in csv export - PHP

Tags: php, export-csv

```
public function exportCsv()
    {
        $this->download_send_headers("subscriber_list_export_" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv");
        $model = $this->getModel('clientsdatas');
        $array = $model->getCsvArray();
        echo $this->array2csv($array);  
        die();
    }

    function array2csv(array &$array)
    {
        if (count($array) == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        ob_start();
        $df = fopen("php://output", 'w');
        fputcsv($df, array_keys(reset($array)));
        foreach ($array as $row) {
            $row['id'] = '="' . $row['id'] . '"';
            fputcsv($df, $row);
        }

        fclose($df);
        return ob_get_clean();
    }

    function download_send_headers($filename) {
        // disable caching
        $now = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s");
        header("Expires: Tue, 03 Jul 2001 06:00:00 GMT");
        header("Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate");
        header("Last-Modified: {$now} GMT");
    
        // force download  
        header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
        header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-Type: application/download");
    
        // disposition / encoding on response body
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename={$filename}");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `array_map` function for each row

Comment: Logic: `(if null or empty) string = '-';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think the problem would be PHP or CSV, you probably were not paying attention to the data-source, because one can query the data as required, without having to manipulate an array:

```
CASE WHEN column IS NULL THEN "-" ELSE column END AS column
```

Comment: yeah at first i was just planning to get csv directly from database, it works as the original code as just export the csv but now I cant figure out how to clean up the data when exporting

Comment: There's also `IF` `THEN` `ELSE`. Postprocessing is a) unnecessary and b) wastes resources.